# path of php file to run cron

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

How to use php file for my cron job after every minute in cpanel.

I have my file under public_html folder.

Searching over google I pass the following path in command text box.

```
/home/addrej/public_html/abc.php
```

================

## SOLVED

I need to write php -q  /home/addrej/public_html/abc.php

Comment: thats ok, whats the problem?

Comment: file is not running.And I dont have my email account for this cpanel so I can't check email.I am performing some db operations and those are not working.But when I am running file as abc.com/abc.php its working

Comment: do you did exactly what I mention in my answer?

Comment: do you have ssh access to server to check weather command is working or not?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah sorry frend I do not get what do you mean ??? and how can I check whether cron is working or not

Comment: do you know what `ssh` is? are you using windows?

Comment: Try this - write below in command text box :
wget http://yourdomain.com/abc.php

Comment: look at my updated answer

Comment: when you solve your problem with a answer, you can accept that answer

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I know if I got answer from any of the answers then I should accept answer but I did it for my own and not get it correct from any answer that's why I did not accept and edited my question with SOLVED. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You must use `/usr/bin/php /home/YourCpanelUsername/public_html/abc.php`

as cron job command instead of :

`/home/addrej/public_html/abc.php`

Comment: there is a / missing before usr.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you managed to find the path of a file on your server by searching Google. I suspect the value you're using could be wrong. One way of getting this information is by uploading the following script to your site (call it `whereami.php`, for example) and accessing it with a web browser (at `yoursite.com/whereami.php`):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
```

To run a PHP script from the command line (or a cron job), you need to know where your PHP application is located. `/usr/bin/php` is usually a safe bet, but your web host will be able to tell you. Pass the script you want to run as a command line argument, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/my/html_docs/abc.php >/dev/null
```

The `>/dev/null` at the end of this line simply discards the output of the PHP script so it isn't emailed to you every time.

Another approach (and one I would actually recommend) is to get your web server involved. That way you can ensure that the script is run in exactly the same environment as the PHP scripts in your website. For example, using the `curl` utility:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://yoursite.com/abc.php >/dev/null
```